# Implementing Retry in Spring Cloud Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm currently trying to implement retry functionality in a Zuul proxy application which is currently providing the urls directly under the routes configuration. Is it possible to achieve retry functionality when you specify the urls directly under the routes (as in the example below)?

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    servicea:
      path: /servicea
      stripPrefix: true
      url: ${servicea.url}
    serviceb:
      path: /serviceab
      stripPrefix: true
      url: ${serviceb.url}

ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
```

The application directs to external applications that are fronted by a load balancer (ALB) so client-side load balancing and service discovery aren't necessary in this case.

The application is using the following dependency for Zuul:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Assuming this is not possible (the docs seem to indicate this), I was hoping to get a bit of help understanding how I should configure the application to enable retry. Based on what I've read the following configuration should work:

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    servicea:
      path: /servicea
      stripPrefix: true
      retryable: true
      serviceId: servicea
    serviceb:
      path: /serviceab
      stripPrefix: true
      retryable: true
      serviceId: serviceb

 servicea:
   ribbon:
     ReadTimeout: 10000
     ConnectTimeout: 10000
     NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
     listOfServers: ${servicea.url}
     stripPrefix: true
     MaxAutoRetries: 1
     OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true

 serviceb:
   ribbon:
     ReadTimeout: 10000
     ConnectTimeout: 10000
     NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
     listOfServers: ${serviceb.url}
     stripPrefix: true
     MaxAutoRetries: 1
     OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true

 ribbon:
   IsSecure: true
   eureka:
     enabled: false
   ReadTimeout: 60000
```

When I attempt to implement it this way I run into an issue where the application doesn't include the hostname specified in the `listOfServers` property. The HTTP Requests obviously fail because of this (the URL is just the protocol, context path, and the rest of the path).

The URLs in the configuration are injected into the PropertySource during startup. One of the URLs would look like the following

`https://servicea.domain/servicea`

In this example the URL is a CNAME for a Load Balancer. The second configuration is routing in the following way

Path into the Spring Cloud Application: 
`/servicea/v1/someeapi`

URL being generated:

`https:/servicea/v1/someapi`

As you can see the application is dropping the host and domain from the URL which is causing requests to fail.

Am I missing something with this configuration?
I'm not currently configuring Spring Cloud anywhere else in the application (Other than providing the `@EnableZuulProxy` and `@EnableRetry` annotations in the main class).

Comment: Where is `servicea.url` set and what does it look like?

Comment: @spencergibb The value is set by a framework which places configurations into the PropertySource during server startup. The first configuration is working as expected. The value would look like the following: ```https://servicea.domain/servicea``` (I've played around with excluding the context path)

Comment: Does it work if you set it directly rather than using placeholders?

Comment: @spencergibb I've tried replacing the placeholder with the value and it doesn't help. The first configuration works correctly with the placeholders or a directly hard-coded value. The weird thing is that logs indicate that the Ribbon load balancer is picking up the value, it's just not adding it to the URLs that it forms.

Comment: How about logs or a project that recreates the problem. I'm just guessing now

Answer (score 0):

> **Retrying Failed Requests**
>   Spring Cloud Netflix offers a variety of ways to make HTTP requests. You can use a load balanced RestTemplate, Ribbon, or Feign. No matter how you choose to create your HTTP requests, there is always a chance that a request may fail. When a request fails, you may want to have the request be retried automatically. To do so when using Sping Cloud Netflix, you need to include Spring Retry on your application’s classpath. When Spring Retry is present, load-balanced RestTemplates, Feign, and Zuul automatically retry any failed requests (assuming your configuration allows doing so).

Doc here: [spring cloud retry](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_retrying-failed-requests.html)